# magento email on checkout

Tags: magento, email, checkout, transactional

I am having a really strange problem with Magento.
Suddenly no emails are sent on successfull checkout.
It worked fine all the time, but I added an custom transactional email with 'new order' as base, but no emails are being send.

Anyone experienced this problem?

Comment: Did you check, if it's still actived at `system->configuration->sales->sales emails`? remember to check the correct tab (order, invoice etc).

Comment: Did you have this issue before or after "I added an custom transactional email with 'new order' as base"? Also did you try to undo this?

Comment: I tried both. The email template for orders is set on the correct template. i also did undo it, but nothing

Comment: Did you check if you receive any error when you access the email template from Admin > System > Transactional Emails ?

Comment: no, but when I try to send an email, I get this error: Invalid transaction email code:4